# My css code in hover does not work with my svg icon and I do not see my error, except that with a google icon the css works well

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to make a CSS hover animation on an svg with the following code css   the bottom but it doesn't work...
With a classic icon it works well I tested. see[Code pen](https://codepen.io/lauryne-13700/pen/abJXmgL) of the result I wish.
Thank you in advance for your help

```css
* Effect global 2*/
 svg#Capa_1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

 svg#Capa_1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    fill: #fa7f28;
}

 svg#Capa_1:after {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: '';
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box; 
    box-sizing: content-box;
}


/* Effect 1 */
 svg#Capa_1 {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s, fill 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s, fill 0.2s;
    transition: background 0.2s, fill 0.2s;
}

 svg#Capa_1:after {
    top: -7px;
    left: -7px;
    padding: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #fff;
                 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
                 filter: drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.8);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transform: scale(.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(.8);
    transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    transform: scale(.8);
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Effect 1a */
 svg#Capa_1:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    fill: #1b1c1f;
    
}

 svg#Capa_1:hover:after {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;

}
```

```html
<svg id="Capa_1" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" height="512" viewbox="0 0 512 512" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m255.107 65.06c5.562 0 10.071-4.509 10.071-10.071v-44.918c0-5.562-4.509-10.071-10.071-10.071s-10.071 4.509-10.071 10.071v44.918c.001 5.562 4.51 10.071 10.071 10.071z"></path><path d="m501.28 345.985-17.791-17.741c-6.329-6.321-14.764-9.803-23.752-9.803-5.747 0-11.264 1.43-16.153 4.109l-33.526-33.486 1.633-1.631c13.601-13.628 13.596-35.773-.001-49.355-4.859-4.868-10.922-8.114-17.531-9.48.91-3.141 1.389-6.431 1.389-9.798 0-9.355-3.634-18.127-10.212-24.678-4.86-4.868-10.922-8.114-17.531-9.48.91-3.141 1.389-6.43 1.389-9.798 0-9.356-3.634-18.127-10.223-24.688-4.976-4.97-11.093-8.116-17.516-9.455 3.436-11.847.5-25.176-8.82-34.512-7.758-7.725-18.285-11.045-28.43-9.969l-66.435-12.575c-10.132-1.922-22.785-3.193-30.772 4.092-.504.46-1.018.989-1.524 1.578-12.384-4.514-26.828-1.826-36.745 8.08-6.579 6.571-10.203 15.339-10.203 24.689 0 3.368.477 6.657 1.386 9.799-6.602 1.365-12.657 4.607-17.5 9.459-6.592 6.565-10.227 15.323-10.234 24.662-.003 3.376.476 6.676 1.39 9.826-6.605 1.362-12.664 4.598-17.522 9.45-6.592 6.585-10.222 15.358-10.222 24.703 0 7.158 2.137 13.977 6.097 19.737-5 1.695-9.58 4.516-13.415 8.347-13.61 13.593-13.615 35.739.009 49.387l1.627 1.62-33.53 33.469c-12.461-5.867-27.814-3.669-38.097 6.601l-17.802 17.752c-6.332 6.324-9.818 14.76-9.819 23.753 0 8.994 3.487 17.431 9.819 23.756l22.217 22.19c3.935 3.931 10.312 3.927 14.242-.008 3.931-3.935 3.927-10.312-.008-14.242l-22.217-22.19c-2.522-2.519-3.911-5.895-3.911-9.505 0-3.609 1.389-6.984 3.905-9.497l17.803-17.753c4.448-4.443 11.256-5.105 16.426-2.014.364.547.785 1.067 1.267 1.55.863.865 1.848 1.528 2.894 2.013l102.093 101.943c.485 1.057 1.151 2.052 2.02 2.922.846.847 1.811 1.502 2.835 1.984 2.159 2.441 3.352 5.559 3.352 8.885 0 3.61-1.389 6.985-3.911 9.504l-17.785 17.764c-5.255 5.232-13.803 5.231-19.042.016l-22.217-22.219c-3.933-3.933-10.309-3.933-14.242 0s-3.933 10.309 0 14.242l22.233 22.235c6.544 6.517 15.138 9.774 23.736 9.774 8.6 0 17.204-3.262 23.756-9.785l17.796-17.775c6.332-6.325 9.819-14.761 9.819-23.756 0-6.419-1.785-12.549-5.104-17.835l37.736-37.69c.04-.041.08-.082.121-.123 4.321-4.467 16.354-3.631 27.991-2.823 8.268.575 17.486 1.214 26.492.176l41.324 41.275c-2.677 4.881-4.106 10.391-4.106 16.129 0 8.985 3.487 17.416 9.819 23.741l17.797 17.775c6.328 6.321 14.763 9.803 23.751 9.803 8.987 0 17.422-3.481 23.751-9.803l107.941-107.81c6.332-6.324 9.819-14.76 9.819-23.754-.001-8.993-3.488-17.429-9.826-23.759zm-267.26-242.55 43.687 8.269-26.149 26.139c-4.045-1.944-9.589-5.57-15.671-11.388-8.325-7.964-14.28-17.159-14.822-22.894-.001-.003-.001-.006-.001-.009 0-.001-.001-.002-.001-.003-.039-.412-.049-.741-.044-.992 1.317-.32 4.815-.675 13.001.878zm-51.058 8.211c5.102-5.097 13.028-5.685 18.793-1.781 3.267 13.698 14.952 26.113 20.209 31.143 3.896 3.728 16.397 14.905 29.015 17.977 1.707 2.447 2.636 5.364 2.636 8.442 0 3.965-1.525 7.672-4.304 10.448-2.771 2.776-6.484 4.304-10.456 4.304-3.973 0-7.686-1.528-10.47-4.317l-.001-.001-.005-.005-45.418-45.336c-2.769-2.765-4.294-6.472-4.294-10.436.001-3.965 1.526-7.672 4.295-10.438zm-26.316 43.947c2.771-2.775 6.48-4.304 10.446-4.304 3.971 0 7.692 1.532 10.481 4.318l36.572 36.499c5.759 5.768 5.759 15.154.02 20.902-2.786 2.775-6.512 4.303-10.491 4.303s-7.705-1.528-10.479-4.291l-.001-.001-27.745-27.739c-.043-.043-.09-.083-.134-.127l-8.68-8.676c-2.785-2.782-4.318-6.496-4.315-10.458.004-3.949 1.532-7.644 4.326-10.426zm-26.366 43.938c2.773-2.769 6.49-4.294 10.468-4.294 3.945 0 7.63 1.503 10.391 4.224l27.83 27.817c2.775 2.764 4.304 6.467 4.304 10.427 0 3.959-1.529 7.662-4.315 10.437-2.772 2.768-6.485 4.293-10.456 4.293-3.977 0-7.702-1.529-10.478-4.293l-10.089-10.077c-.002-.003-.005-.005-.007-.007l-17.647-17.626c-2.782-2.779-4.314-6.491-4.314-10.451 0-3.959 1.532-7.672 4.313-10.45zm-17.54 52.786c2.785-2.782 6.507-4.314 10.48-4.314 3.972 0 7.693 1.531 10.477 4.311l10.103 10.091c2.776 2.764 4.304 6.467 4.304 10.427s-1.529 7.662-4.325 10.448c-2.771 2.775-6.484 4.304-10.456 4.304-3.973 0-7.686-1.528-10.477-4.324l-1.265-1.26c-.017-.017-.03-.035-.046-.051-.019-.018-.039-.034-.058-.052l-8.727-8.693c-5.759-5.771-5.764-15.14-.01-20.887zm205.234 114.458c-3.931-3.936-10.308-3.939-14.242-.009l-8.96 8.949c-8.514 8.514-23.941 7.442-38.86 6.407-16.201-1.126-32.954-2.288-43.795 8.842l-37.095 37.05-92.763-92.627 32.828-32.769c5.426 3.326 11.687 5.109 18.238 5.109 9.359 0 18.135-3.628 24.69-10.195 6.599-6.572 10.234-15.343 10.234-24.699 0-.087-.006-.173-.006-.26.087.001.174.006.261.006 9.346 0 18.115-3.617 24.679-10.173 6.599-6.572 10.234-15.344 10.234-24.699 0-.087-.006-.173-.006-.26.088 0 .176.006.265.006 9.343 0 18.117-3.613 24.725-10.194 6.86-6.871 10.253-15.917 10.188-24.944.09.001.18.006.27.006 9.359-.001 18.134-3.628 24.699-10.205 6.579-6.571 10.203-15.339 10.203-24.689 0-6.539-1.778-12.79-5.093-18.205l28.773-28.761c2.144-2.135 4.788-3.475 7.559-4.028.3-.032.596-.08.889-.138 4.446-.613 9.115.759 12.515 4.145 5.759 5.769 5.759 15.155.021 20.903l-8.763 8.727c-.029.029-.06.055-.089.084l-10.093 10.076c-3.936 3.93-3.94 10.307-.009 14.242 3.932 3.936 10.308 3.939 14.242.009l8.798-8.786c.002-.002.004-.004.006-.006l1.33-1.325c5.775-5.722 15.131-5.71 20.9.051 2.776 2.764 4.305 6.467 4.305 10.427 0 3.959-1.529 7.662-4.327 10.448l-8.813 8.831c-.001.001-.002.002-.003.004l-10.092 10.051c-3.941 3.925-3.954 10.302-.029 14.242 3.925 3.941 10.301 3.953 14.242.029l10.138-10.097c2.771-2.776 6.484-4.304 10.456-4.304 3.973 0 7.687 1.528 10.478 4.324 2.776 2.765 4.304 6.468 4.304 10.428 0 3.959-1.528 7.662-4.32 10.442l-17.57 17.577c-3.932 3.934-3.931 10.31.002 14.242 1.967 1.966 4.543 2.948 7.12 2.948 2.578 0 5.156-.984 7.122-2.951l8.611-8.614c.049-.047.102-.088.151-.137 2.771-2.776 6.484-4.304 10.456-4.304 3.973 0 7.686 1.528 10.467 4.314 5.753 5.747 5.748 15.117 0 20.875l-8.755 8.745c-.003.003-.007.006-.01.009s-.006.007-.009.01l-13.896 13.879c-3.935 3.931-3.939 10.308-.009 14.243 1.967 1.969 4.547 2.954 7.126 2.954 2.575 0 5.151-.982 7.117-2.945l6.797-6.789 32.577 32.539-92.755 92.642-33.234-33.194c2.317-1.49 4.534-3.242 6.615-5.323l8.955-8.944c3.937-3.929 3.941-10.306.01-14.241zm169.078 12.472-107.941 107.81c-2.525 2.522-5.905 3.911-9.517 3.911s-6.992-1.389-9.518-3.912l-17.797-17.775c-2.522-2.518-3.911-5.888-3.911-9.489 0-3.6 1.389-6.97 3.911-9.489l107.941-107.81c2.526-2.523 5.905-3.912 9.518-3.912 3.612 0 6.992 1.389 9.524 3.918l17.791 17.741c2.522 2.519 3.911 5.893 3.911 9.503-.001 3.611-1.39 6.986-3.912 9.504z"></path><path d="m121.378 56.57c1.966 1.962 4.54 2.942 7.114 2.942 2.58 0 5.161-.986 7.128-2.957 3.929-3.937 3.923-10.313-.014-14.242l-36.698-36.625c-3.936-3.929-10.313-3.924-14.242.014-3.929 3.937-3.923 10.313.014 14.242z"></path><path d="m381.722 59.512c2.575 0 5.151-.982 7.117-2.945l36.67-36.626c3.935-3.93 3.939-10.307.008-14.242-3.93-3.935-10.306-3.939-14.242-.008l-36.67 36.626c-3.935 3.93-3.939 10.307-.008 14.242 1.967 1.969 4.546 2.953 7.125 2.953z"></path><path d="m62.819 433.204c-3.899 3.966-3.845 10.343.122 14.242l.029.028c1.957 1.924 4.498 2.882 7.038 2.882 2.607 0 5.214-1.009 7.189-3.018 3.899-3.966 3.83-10.357-.136-14.256-3.965-3.899-10.341-3.844-14.242.122z"></path><path d="m342.606 352.267c1.532 0 3.086-.349 4.545-1.084 4.966-2.505 6.961-8.561 4.457-13.527-2.505-4.966-8.562-6.962-13.527-4.457l-.056.028c-4.966 2.505-6.933 8.547-4.429 13.513 1.768 3.508 5.324 5.527 9.01 5.527z"></path></svg>
```

but it doesn't work...
With a classic icon it works well. see[Code pen](https://codepen.io/lauryne-13700/pen/abJXmgL) of the result I wish.
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: you need to add another element where to set your styles. it can be a <rect> covering the whole svg. from there you can draw gradients. https://jsfiddle.net/sg6wcx5u/

Comment: Could I just be sure I understand what you want - on hover the hands change color and a black ring grows around them. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replaced elements cannot have before or after pseudo elements so while your svg changes color on hover it does not show its circular shadow.

This snippet puts the svg in a wrapper, and the wrapper has an after pseudo element which expands and becomes opaque on hover.

Note: pre fixes have been removed to aid clarity and the CSS rearranged to cluster the wrapper and the svg settings separately. Margins have also been removed but can of course be put back (on the wrapper) depending on what is required.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  }
  
.wrapper::after {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: ''; 
    box-sizing: content-box;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #fff;
    filter: drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
    transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    transform: scale(.8);
    opacity: 0;
}

.wrapper:hover::after {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}

 svg#Capa_1 {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    fill: #fa7f28;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    transition: background 0.2s, fill 0.2s;
}

 svg#Capa_1:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    fill: #1b1c1f;    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg id="Capa_1" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" height="512" viewbox="0 0 512 512" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m255.107 65.06c5.562 0 10.071-4.509 10.071-10.071v-44.918c0-5.562-4.509-10.071-10.071-10.071s-10.071 4.509-10.071 10.071v44.918c.001 5.562 4.51 10.071 10.071 10.071z"></path><path d="m501.28 345.985-17.791-17.741c-6.329-6.321-14.764-9.803-23.752-9.803-5.747 0-11.264 1.43-16.153 4.109l-33.526-33.486 1.633-1.631c13.601-13.628 13.596-35.773-.001-49.355-4.859-4.868-10.922-8.114-17.531-9.48.91-3.141 1.389-6.431 1.389-9.798 0-9.355-3.634-18.127-10.212-24.678-4.86-4.868-10.922-8.114-17.531-9.48.91-3.141 1.389-6.43 1.389-9.798 0-9.356-3.634-18.127-10.223-24.688-4.976-4.97-11.093-8.116-17.516-9.455 3.436-11.847.5-25.176-8.82-34.512-7.758-7.725-18.285-11.045-28.43-9.969l-66.435-12.575c-10.132-1.922-22.785-3.193-30.772 4.092-.504.46-1.018.989-1.524 1.578-12.384-4.514-26.828-1.826-36.745 8.08-6.579 6.571-10.203 15.339-10.203 24.689 0 3.368.477 6.657 1.386 9.799-6.602 1.365-12.657 4.607-17.5 9.459-6.592 6.565-10.227 15.323-10.234 24.662-.003 3.376.476 6.676 1.39 9.826-6.605 1.362-12.664 4.598-17.522 9.45-6.592 6.585-10.222 15.358-10.222 24.703 0 7.158 2.137 13.977 6.097 19.737-5 1.695-9.58 4.516-13.415 8.347-13.61 13.593-13.615 35.739.009 49.387l1.627 1.62-33.53 33.469c-12.461-5.867-27.814-3.669-38.097 6.601l-17.802 17.752c-6.332 6.324-9.818 14.76-9.819 23.753 0 8.994 3.487 17.431 9.819 23.756l22.217 22.19c3.935 3.931 10.312 3.927 14.242-.008 3.931-3.935 3.927-10.312-.008-14.242l-22.217-22.19c-2.522-2.519-3.911-5.895-3.911-9.505 0-3.609 1.389-6.984 3.905-9.497l17.803-17.753c4.448-4.443 11.256-5.105 16.426-2.014.364.547.785 1.067 1.267 1.55.863.865 1.848 1.528 2.894 2.013l102.093 101.943c.485 1.057 1.151 2.052 2.02 2.922.846.847 1.811 1.502 2.835 1.984 2.159 2.441 3.352 5.559 3.352 8.885 0 3.61-1.389 6.985-3.911 9.504l-17.785 17.764c-5.255 5.232-13.803 5.231-19.042.016l-22.217-22.219c-3.933-3.933-10.309-3.933-14.242 0s-3.933 10.309 0 14.242l22.233 22.235c6.544 6.517 15.138 9.774 23.736 9.774 8.6 0 17.204-3.262 23.756-9.785l17.796-17.775c6.332-6.325 9.819-14.761 9.819-23.756 0-6.419-1.785-12.549-5.104-17.835l37.736-37.69c.04-.041.08-.082.121-.123 4.321-4.467 16.354-3.631 27.991-2.823 8.268.575 17.486 1.214 26.492.176l41.324 41.275c-2.677 4.881-4.106 10.391-4.106 16.129 0 8.985 3.487 17.416 9.819 23.741l17.797 17.775c6.328 6.321 14.763 9.803 23.751 9.803 8.987 0 17.422-3.481 23.751-9.803l107.941-107.81c6.332-6.324 9.819-14.76 9.819-23.754-.001-8.993-3.488-17.429-9.826-23.759zm-267.26-242.55 43.687 8.269-26.149 26.139c-4.045-1.944-9.589-5.57-15.671-11.388-8.325-7.964-14.28-17.159-14.822-22.894-.001-.003-.001-.006-.001-.009 0-.001-.001-.002-.001-.003-.039-.412-.049-.741-.044-.992 1.317-.32 4.815-.675 13.001.878zm-51.058 8.211c5.102-5.097 13.028-5.685 18.793-1.781 3.267 13.698 14.952 26.113 20.209 31.143 3.896 3.728 16.397 14.905 29.015 17.977 1.707 2.447 2.636 5.364 2.636 8.442 0 3.965-1.525 7.672-4.304 10.448-2.771 2.776-6.484 4.304-10.456 4.304-3.973 0-7.686-1.528-10.47-4.317l-.001-.001-.005-.005-45.418-45.336c-2.769-2.765-4.294-6.472-4.294-10.436.001-3.965 1.526-7.672 4.295-10.438zm-26.316 43.947c2.771-2.775 6.48-4.304 10.446-4.304 3.971 0 7.692 1.532 10.481 4.318l36.572 36.499c5.759 5.768 5.759 15.154.02 20.902-2.786 2.775-6.512 4.303-10.491 4.303s-7.705-1.528-10.479-4.291l-.001-.001-27.745-27.739c-.043-.043-.09-.083-.134-.127l-8.68-8.676c-2.785-2.782-4.318-6.496-4.315-10.458.004-3.949 1.532-7.644 4.326-10.426zm-26.366 43.938c2.773-2.769 6.49-4.294 10.468-4.294 3.945 0 7.63 1.503 10.391 4.224l27.83 27.817c2.775 2.764 4.304 6.467 4.304 10.427 0 3.959-1.529 7.662-4.315 10.437-2.772 2.768-6.485 4.293-10.456 4.293-3.977 0-7.702-1.529-10.478-4.293l-10.089-10.077c-.002-.003-.005-.005-.007-.007l-17.647-17.626c-2.782-2.779-4.314-6.491-4.314-10.451 0-3.959 1.532-7.672 4.313-10.45zm-17.54 52.786c2.785-2.782 6.507-4.314 10.48-4.314 3.972 0 7.693 1.531 10.477 4.311l10.103 10.091c2.776 2.764 4.304 6.467 4.304 10.427s-1.529 7.662-4.325 10.448c-2.771 2.775-6.484 4.304-10.456 4.304-3.973 0-7.686-1.528-10.477-4.324l-1.265-1.26c-.017-.017-.03-.035-.046-.051-.019-.018-.039-.034-.058-.052l-8.727-8.693c-5.759-5.771-5.764-15.14-.01-20.887zm205.234 114.458c-3.931-3.936-10.308-3.939-14.242-.009l-8.96 8.949c-8.514 8.514-23.941 7.442-38.86 6.407-16.201-1.126-32.954-2.288-43.795 8.842l-37.095 37.05-92.763-92.627 32.828-32.769c5.426 3.326 11.687 5.109 18.238 5.109 9.359 0 18.135-3.628 24.69-10.195 6.599-6.572 10.234-15.343 10.234-24.699 0-.087-.006-.173-.006-.26.087.001.174.006.261.006 9.346 0 18.115-3.617 24.679-10.173 6.599-6.572 10.234-15.344 10.234-24.699 0-.087-.006-.173-.006-.26.088 0 .176.006.265.006 9.343 0 18.117-3.613 24.725-10.194 6.86-6.871 10.253-15.917 10.188-24.944.09.001.18.006.27.006 9.359-.001 18.134-3.628 24.699-10.205 6.579-6.571 10.203-15.339 10.203-24.689 0-6.539-1.778-12.79-5.093-18.205l28.773-28.761c2.144-2.135 4.788-3.475 7.559-4.028.3-.032.596-.08.889-.138 4.446-.613 9.115.759 12.515 4.145 5.759 5.769 5.759 15.155.021 20.903l-8.763 8.727c-.029.029-.06.055-.089.084l-10.093 10.076c-3.936 3.93-3.94 10.307-.009 14.242 3.932 3.936 10.308 3.939 14.242.009l8.798-8.786c.002-.002.004-.004.006-.006l1.33-1.325c5.775-5.722 15.131-5.71 20.9.051 2.776 2.764 4.305 6.467 4.305 10.427 0 3.959-1.529 7.662-4.327 10.448l-8.813 8.831c-.001.001-.002.002-.003.004l-10.092 10.051c-3.941 3.925-3.954 10.302-.029 14.242 3.925 3.941 10.301 3.953 14.242.029l10.138-10.097c2.771-2.776 6.484-4.304 10.456-4.304 3.973 0 7.687 1.528 10.478 4.324 2.776 2.765 4.304 6.468 4.304 10.428 0 3.959-1.528 7.662-4.32 10.442l-17.57 17.577c-3.932 3.934-3.931 10.31.002 14.242 1.967 1.966 4.543 2.948 7.12 2.948 2.578 0 5.156-.984 7.122-2.951l8.611-8.614c.049-.047.102-.088.151-.137 2.771-2.776 6.484-4.304 10.456-4.304 3.973 0 7.686 1.528 10.467 4.314 5.753 5.747 5.748 15.117 0 20.875l-8.755 8.745c-.003.003-.007.006-.01.009s-.006.007-.009.01l-13.896 13.879c-3.935 3.931-3.939 10.308-.009 14.243 1.967 1.969 4.547 2.954 7.126 2.954 2.575 0 5.151-.982 7.117-2.945l6.797-6.789 32.577 32.539-92.755 92.642-33.234-33.194c2.317-1.49 4.534-3.242 6.615-5.323l8.955-8.944c3.937-3.929 3.941-10.306.01-14.241zm169.078 12.472-107.941 107.81c-2.525 2.522-5.905 3.911-9.517 3.911s-6.992-1.389-9.518-3.912l-17.797-17.775c-2.522-2.518-3.911-5.888-3.911-9.489 0-3.6 1.389-6.97 3.911-9.489l107.941-107.81c2.526-2.523 5.905-3.912 9.518-3.912 3.612 0 6.992 1.389 9.524 3.918l17.791 17.741c2.522 2.519 3.911 5.893 3.911 9.503-.001 3.611-1.39 6.986-3.912 9.504z"></path><path d="m121.378 56.57c1.966 1.962 4.54 2.942 7.114 2.942 2.58 0 5.161-.986 7.128-2.957 3.929-3.937 3.923-10.313-.014-14.242l-36.698-36.625c-3.936-3.929-10.313-3.924-14.242.014-3.929 3.937-3.923 10.313.014 14.242z"></path><path d="m381.722 59.512c2.575 0 5.151-.982 7.117-2.945l36.67-36.626c3.935-3.93 3.939-10.307.008-14.242-3.93-3.935-10.306-3.939-14.242-.008l-36.67 36.626c-3.935 3.93-3.939 10.307-.008 14.242 1.967 1.969 4.546 2.953 7.125 2.953z"></path><path d="m62.819 433.204c-3.899 3.966-3.845 10.343.122 14.242l.029.028c1.957 1.924 4.498 2.882 7.038 2.882 2.607 0 5.214-1.009 7.189-3.018 3.899-3.966 3.83-10.357-.136-14.256-3.965-3.899-10.341-3.844-14.242.122z"></path><path d="m342.606 352.267c1.532 0 3.086-.349 4.545-1.084 4.966-2.505 6.961-8.561 4.457-13.527-2.505-4.966-8.562-6.962-13.527-4.457l-.056.028c-4.966 2.505-6.933 8.547-4.429 13.513 1.768 3.508 5.324 5.527 9.01 5.527z"></path></svg>
</div>
```